# Taylor expansion of rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I want to taylor expand the following function (in the complex plane):

$$(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!})^{-1}$$

I am told that the result is:

$$1+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{14}{6!}z^4+O(z^6)$$

I do not see how to obtain this. The only thing I have tried is using the taylor expansion of $(1-z)^{-1}$. But using this I can only obtain the second term of the expansion written above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall from [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+O(x^3)$

Now, set $x= z^2/3!-z^4/5!$ and don't forget the second order term $(z^2/3!-z^4/5!)^2$.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't this only true for $|z|<1$?

Comment: OK. So the expression above is only valid in a domain that satisfies $\left|\frac{z^2}{3!}-\frac{z^4}{5!}\right|<1$?

Comment: No.  The expansion is not a full series.  Note from Taylor's Theorem that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+o(x^2)$where we are using the little $o$ notation.

Comment: What do you mean by full series?

Comment: We are truncating a series, not writing one.  [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) is not Taylor's Series.  If we write $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$, then the series converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges elsewhere.  But we can write $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+O(x^3)$ without restricting $x$.